# superbible lnk2019 glew

Tags: windows, opengl, glew

I'm working with Superbible 5th edition and I've already come across a problem with the first program. I've been able to fix a good amount of problems by adding in Windows.h and taking out the line #define FREEGLUT_STATIC, but I can't get past the linker errors I have right now.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GLTools.h>
#include <GLShaderManager.h>

#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <gl\glut.h>

GLBatch triangleBatch;
GLShaderManager shaderManager;

void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void SetupRC()
{
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

GLfloat vVerts[] = 
{ 
    -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f
};

triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
triangleBatch.End();
}

 void RenderScene(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
triangleBatch.Draw();

glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
glutCreateWindow("Triangle");
glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

GLenum err = glewInit();
if(GLEW_OK != err)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    return 1;
}

SetupRC();

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

and these are the errors I am getting:

```
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GLBatch::End(void)" (?End@GLBatch@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl SetupRC(void)" (?SetupRC@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GLBatch::Begin(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?Begin@GLBatch@@QAEXIII@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl SetupRC(void)" (?SetupRC@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall GLShaderManager::InitializeStockShaders(void)" (?InitializeStockShaders@GLShaderManager@@QAE_NXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl SetupRC(void)" (?SetupRC@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall GLBatch::CopyVertexData3f(float (*)[3])" (?CopyVertexData3f@GLBatch@@QAEXPAY02M@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall GLBatch::CopyVertexData3f(float *)" (?CopyVertexData3f@GLBatch@@QAEXPAM@Z)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall GLBatch::Draw(void)" (?Draw@GLBatch@@UAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderScene(void)" (?RenderScene@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl GLShaderManager::UseStockShader(enum GLT_STOCK_SHADER,...)" (?UseStockShader@GLShaderManager@@QAAHW4GLT_STOCK_SHADER@@ZZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl RenderScene(void)" (?RenderScene@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glewGetErrorString referenced in function _main
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glewInit referenced in function _main
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl gltSetWorkingDirectory(char const *)" (?gltSetWorkingDirectory@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GLBatch::GLBatch(void)" (??0GLBatch@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'triangleBatch''(void)" (??__EtriangleBatch@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GLShaderManager::GLShaderManager(void)" (??0GLShaderManager@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'shaderManager''(void)" (??__EshaderManager@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall GLBatch::~GLBatch(void)" (??1GLBatch@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'triangleBatch''(void)" (??__FtriangleBatch@@YAXXZ)
1>triangle test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall GLShaderManager::~GLShaderManager(void)" (??1GLShaderManager@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'shaderManager''(void)" (??__FshaderManager@@YAXXZ)
```

It should be able to compile with just the included files from the website, but it's not.

Comment: Can you compile the OpenGL equivalent of a _Hello, World!_ program?

Comment: Considering that this is the first program in the book, I am not sure how to find something that is simpler than this. If there is a set of code I could test this with, I would be willing to try

Comment: @sarnold: The missing symbols aren't from OpenGL nor GLut, so I expect these to be set up properly, but the other libs seem to be missing.

Comment: The book only makes mention of the libraries GLTools.lib and freeglut_static.lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add some libraries to the project that provide the mentioned function bodies. You can do this using the project properties ("Linker", "Input", "Additional Dependencies") or a `#pragma` line anywhere in your source code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libraryname.lib")
```

I don't know about the library name; it's most likely explained somewhere in the book, but it might be `GLTools.lib` or `GLShaderManager.lib` (or something different; you should have these files somewhere alongside the include files (but in a `lib` directory).

Edit: You're missing the lib file for glew as well (`glew32.lib`).

Comment: The book and source files for Superbible as well as the instructions make no mention of glew32.lib or GLShaderManager.lib but I do have GLTools.lib.

Comment: Then try `GLTools.lib`, it might include everything missing.